# On the derivation of the jerk term in tensor notation

Tags: kinematics, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, jerk

The jerk vector $\mathbf{J}(t)$ may be (element-wise) written as

$$J^{i} = \frac{d A^{i}}{d t} + \Gamma^{i}_{jk} A^{j}V^{k}~~~~(*).$$

However, I can't correctly get the second term of the RHS above. In particular, given the definition of Acceleration vector $\mathbf{A}(t)$

$$A^{i} = \frac{d V^{i}}{d t} + \Gamma^{i}_{jk} V^{j}V^{k}~~~~(**),$$

one can say

$$\frac{d}{dt}[\Gamma^{i}_{jk} V^{j}V^{k}] = \Gamma^{i}_{jk}\frac{d}{dt}[V^{j}V^{k}] = \Gamma^{i}_{jk}[A^{j}V^{k} + A^{k}V^{j}].$$

The symmetry of the Christoffel symbol with respect to its lower indices implies that

$$\Gamma^{i}_{jk}A^{j}V^{k} = \Gamma^{i}_{kj} A^{k}V^{j},$$

based on which I finally conclude that

$$\frac{d}{dt}[\Gamma^{i}_{jk} V^{j}V^{k}] = 2\Gamma^{i}_{jk}A^{j}V^{k},$$

in which there is that spurious factor of **2**!

Can one explain my mistake here?

Comment: Please can you explain your starting point and where you are trying to get to?

Comment: @CameronGibson: I want to derive the second term of the equation (*) which is $\Gamma^{i}_{jk} A^{j}V^{k}$. But, as the question reads, I have ended up with $2\Gamma^{i}_{jk} A^{j}V^{k}$. So, I'd like to know what mistake has yielded that $2$ factor.

Comment: You've said what jerk definition you want to end up with by writing (*), which one have you started with?

Comment: @CameronGibson: I have started from the second term of (**) and applied $\frac{d}{dt}$ to that expecting to get $\Gamma^{i}_{jk} A^{j}V^{k}$.

Comment: Thanks for adding (**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have applied the differentiation to $\mathbf{A}(t)$ rather than its components $A^{i}(t)$. If so, we get

$$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{J}(t) = &\frac{d}{dt} \mathbf{A}(t) \\= & \frac{d}{dt}[A^{i}(t)\mathbf{Z}_{i}(t)] \\ =& \mathbf{Z}_{i}(t)\frac{d}{dt}A^{i}(t) + A^{i}(t)\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{Z}_{i}(t) \\ =& \mathbf{Z}_{i}(t)\frac{d}{dt}A^{i}(t) + A^{i}(t) [\frac{d \mathbf{Z}_{i}(t)}{dZ^{j}(t)}\frac{dZ^{j}(t)}{dt}]\\=&\mathbf{Z}_{i}(t)\frac{d}{dt}A^{i}(t) + A^{i}(t)\Gamma^{k}_{ij}\mathbf{Z}_{k}V^{j} \\=&\mathbf{Z}_{i}(t)\frac{d}{dt}A^{i}(t) + A^{k}(t)\Gamma^{i}_{kj}\mathbf{Z}_{i}V^{j} \\=&\mathbf{Z}_{i}(t)[\frac{d}{dt}A^{i}(t) + A^{j}(t)\Gamma^{i}_{jk}V^{k}]
\end{aligned}$$